# FLASK uploads broken image

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to upload pictures and display it in a URL.

my server:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'static/uploads')
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route('/post_pic',methods=['POST','GET'])
def post_picture():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file1 = request.files['image']
        path1 = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file1.filename)
        file1.save(path1)
        return_status = {"success":"true"}
        return jsonify(return_status)

    list_of_files = glob.glob(UPLOAD_FOLDER + '/*') # get latest file
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)    
    return render_template("show_pic3.html", file1=latest_file)
```

`show_pic3.hrml` code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>show_pic</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{{url_for('static', filename=file1)}}" align= "middle" />
</body>
</html>
```

I then use POST request to upload picture which doesn't show any problems. but after I use GET on the same endpoint, the image became broken.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, a web server will handle a load of content (nginx). If you are trying to save content then the best option is to save them somewhere in a location and use the [send_from_directory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory) with a get image as an API call.

A quick fix for your question would be to replace the `/app/static/` with nothing at the end before rendering.

```
list_of_files = glob.glob(UPLOAD_FOLDER + '/*') # get latest file
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime).replace("/app/static/","")
return render_template("show_pic3.html", file1=latest_file)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your quick fix does work. But I'm still confused about `send_from_directory` because I only saw the use to get the file to download examples.